# Difference between Appcompat.Widget and Widget.AppCompat in appcompat-v7 resources file?

Tags: android, material-design, android-resources, android-styles

In `appcompat-v7:22.2.0`, two resource hierarchies declared in `values.xml` are confusing to me.

For example, below styles are found in same file: `values.xml` in `appcompat-v7:22.2.0`

```
<!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml -->

<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" 
parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>

<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" 
parent="Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is effectively no difference.

From [line 323 of styles_base.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/39b32a9feea6b821d6a5c92202c400aa1f252200/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml#L323-325):

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
       parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
</style>
```

The `Toolbar.Title` base style is just an alias to the `ActionBar.Title` style. I am assuming that Google organized it like this because they are attempting to replace the word "Action Bar" with the word "Toolbar" in our vocabulary, but wanted to make these styles easy to find.

> What's the difference between the resource hierarchy of the two: Appcompat.Widget and Widget.AppCompat?

Someone just decided to name them differently. Since both styles have an explicit parent, neither one will inherit any attributes by default anyway. My guess is that it is simply a mistake.